# Why in some places instead of "ja" they say "nu"?

Tags: etymology, history, regional

I am curious as to what is the origin of the expression "nu" as "ja", as it is quite a strange divergence from the original word.

Thanks

Comment: Never heard it in this way. I know "nu" in "im Nu" (after a short time) or as an colloquial abbreviation of "nun" in "Und nu?" (And now?).

Comment: This is specifically Yiddish, not German: http://forward.com/articles/12736/just-say-nu-

Comment: Examples? Sources?

Comment: Where do they say that?

Comment: Sachsen. Klingt manchmal wie "no" und macht es noch verwirrender.

Comment: http://youtu.be/DWwN-Ni0KAg

Comment: In Bavarian, we have a similar exclamation "No!" which is sometimes used to express strong agreement. It means quite the same as "Und wie!" ("And how!") in Standard German, though. The Saxons seem to use it to some additional occasions and more frequently.

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: nice video. Because Dbuggers location is Dresden this might be exactly what he meant. But has anybody an idea of the origin? Found just these: http://www.geschichtsforum.de/f72/das-best-tigende-s-chsische-no-ein-westslawisches-substrat-49353/ http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nu_nun_ja

Comment: Taken from http://www.morgenpost.de/kolumne/philipp/article828702/Unter-Sachsen-So-wird-man-schnell-wieder-gesund.html: Der Dresden-Sachse gebraucht das "Nu" zuerst, um ja zu sagen oder sein Einverständnis zu erklären. Es beruht auf dem sprachlichen Ursprung des Landes, nämlich dem Slawischen. Noch heute sagen die Nachbarn in Tschechien "Ano" für "Ja", verkürzen aber meistens auf "No". Beim Sachsen heißt das "Nu".

Comment: @Robert Aber nicht in ganz Sachsen. Ich bin in Leipzig geboren, und bis zum Umzug meiner Familie nach Dresden (da war ich 9) war mir das Wort unbekannt.

Comment: Note in Saxonia, there is the word `nu` (I'd say it's pronouced `[⁠nʉ⁠]`) meaning `yes`, but in other regions like Berlin and Brandenburg there is also the word `ne` `[n⁠ə⁠]` often used as question to ask for agreement like `Das Eis schmeckt gut, ne? Ja.` (It might sound similar.) Note that there's also `nee` (also written `ne`) `[nɛː]` with a long wovel meaning `Nein` (no).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Nu" is a word which is used regionally to express agreement or encouragement and then only in spoken language.

My grandmother was from Sudetenland which is now Czech Republic she used it. Also friends of mine from an area South of Leipzig in Saxonia are using it.

They usually say "Nu, nu" - I almost always heard them saying it twice in a row.

For example:

Question:

```
"Kann ich noch eine Tasse Kaffee haben?"
```

Response:

```
"Nu, nu ..."
```

Then the person would pour you a cup of coffee.

Comment: This is a nice start, because it gives an idea of the region where it is used, but I do not think that it attempts to answer the question of the origin of the word.

Comment: Right, I missed that.